# c# get client username

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm trying to get my logged username of my client, but I get still server-information. This are my trys:

```
Environment.UserName;
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: You haven't said it, but several of your attempts suggest that this is for ASP.Net. If this is the case, you don't get the information unless you turn on Windows Authentication

Comment: yes it is for ASP.Net 4.5

Comment: Deploy your application on server and then try, After deploying the applicaiton in windows authentication mode on you will get this information.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue, have you found a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Typically I use User.Identity.Name, which returns the login name the user accessing the application enters.

e.g.`var loginName = User.Identity.Name;`